# JQuery UI MultiSelect plugin for a dropdown checkbox menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to use the jQuery UI MultiSelect, found here: http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos
for some time now, but I have been unable to install it. I've searched the web and I haven't found any tutorials on how to do so. I would like to install the plugin and use it to dynamically create a dropdown checkbox menu.

Answer (score 0):

Multiselect can be implemented using JQuery UI and Jquery for multi select

```
$(function() {
        $( "#multiselect" ).selectable();
      });
```

Codepen- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/jrMbYE

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Include CDNs- Jquery UI and Jquery - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js
for testing in local

Comment: I'm trying to use multiselect for checkboxes, and I think the normal way is to use the plugin I posted. I want it to be a dropdown list of checkbox options. If anyone has any advice on how to do this using the plugin then please post.

Comment: are you trying for example using that plugin for multiselect checkbox?

Comment: Github is having all the files and demos of Jquery UI multiselect - https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget
and demos are available - http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#basic
and demo code - https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/tree/master/demos

Comment: i just created one sample project following the example in codepen - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/MejaLJ

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do, but I am not sure if I have to include any files into my directory for it to work. I have tried and it is not working like your demo.

Comment: Yes you need to include all Css and Js files to make it work - jquery,multi select.js jquery UI as well